# exception of vm budget error in tabHost With ActivityGroup

Tags: android

I have Following exception in Tabhost with activityGroup 
I have used Following code for setcontentView

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.language, null);
this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
```

I have Got following exception in My some of Activities

```
    01-28 16:26:23.550: E/dalvikvm-heap(2730): 768000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
01-28 16:26:23.550: E/(2730): VM won't let us allocate 768000 bytes
01-28 16:26:23.550: D/skia(2730): --- decoder->decode returned false
01-28 16:26:23.558: D/AndroidRuntime(2730): Shutting down VM
01-28 16:26:23.558: W/dalvikvm(2730): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b170)
01-28 16:26:23.558: W/System.err(2730): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.milagemaster/com.milagemaster.Activity_Share}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2335)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:648)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:379)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:851)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)
01-28 16:26:23.566: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 16:26:23.574: W/System.err(2730): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at com.milagemaster.Activity_Share.onCreate(Activity_Share.java:30)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730):     ... 31 more
01-28 16:26:23.589: W/System.err(2730): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-28 16:26:23.597: W/System.err(2730):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:171)
01-28 16:26:23.597: W/System.err(2730):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-28 16:26:23.597: W/System.err(2730):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
01-28 16:26:23.597: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
01-28 16:26:23.597: W/System.err(2730):     ... 41 more
01-28 16:26:23.597: W/System.err(2730): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
01-28 16:26:23.613: W/System.err(2730):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-28 16:26:23.613: W/System.err(2730):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:447)
01-28 16:26:23.613: W/System.err(2730):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
01-28 16:26:23.613: W/System.err(2730):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
01-28 16:26:23.613: W/System.err(2730):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1705)
01-28 16:26:23.613: W/System.err(2730):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
01-28 16:26:23.613: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850)
01-28 16:26:23.613: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1799)
01-28 16:26:23.613: W/System.err(2730):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:283)
01-28 16:26:23.613: W/System.err(2730):     ... 45 more
```

here is the xml file for my tab activity

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lLayoutHome"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/title" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageLine"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/mileage" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:tabStripEnabled="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the xml file for my activity

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.milagemaster.utility.Header
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeHome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/title" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddData"
            style="@style/TitleTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/adddata"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeMainAdd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lnrTitle" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgShadow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_title" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeAddData"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeSpinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativetitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_blue" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSelVehicle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/vehcile"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnSelectVehicle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_barsMain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativetitle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box_middle_white"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativetitle"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtAddGal"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/costpergal"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtAddGal"
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/background_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:hint="@string/cost"
                            android:maxLength="10"
                            android:numeric="integer|decimal"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/mileage"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtCurrencyGal"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtAddGallons"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/gallonsAdded"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtAddGallons"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:hint="@string/gallonsAdded"
                        android:maxLength="10"
                        android:numeric="integer|decimal"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/mileage"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTotalCost"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/tcost"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edtTotalCost"
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:background="@drawable/background_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:hint="@string/tcost"
                            android:maxLength="10"
                            android:numeric="integer|decimal"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/mileage"
                            android:textSize="14sp" >

                            <requestFocus />
                        </EditText>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtCurrencyTotal"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtFilledTank"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/fiiledTank"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/mileage"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <!--
                         <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/tgbtnFillTank"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/full_off"
                        android:textOff=""
                        android:textOn="" />

                    -->

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/tgbtnFillTank"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/tankfull"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:button="@drawable/button_radio"

                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="@string/yes"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/tankNotFull"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:button="@drawable/button_radio"

                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="@string/no"
                            android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtOdometerset"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/odometersetup"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/rdbManually"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:button="@drawable/button_radio"
                            android:checked="false"
                            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="@string/totalmileage"
                            android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/rdbTrip"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:button="@drawable/button_radio"
                            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="@string/tripmielage"
                            android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtOdometer"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/osometer"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtOdometer"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:hint="@string/odometerreading"
                        android:maxLength="10"
                        android:numeric="integer|decimal"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/mileage"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtNote"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/note"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editNote"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/background_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:hint="@string/notefillup"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:maxLength="200"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/mileage"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/mileage"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post you layout XML too, where the error seems to be `Error inflating class <unknown>`

Comment: I am not getting this error on first time ,when i navigate 3 to 4 times in app this error comes

Answer (score 0):

Check you XML file. because may be it cause by XMl fil

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.milagemaster/com.milagemaster.Activity_home}: **android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class** 
So, post your XML layout.
Thanks